# TPL BackgroundThread UIThread Graphics Updates

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, task-parallel-library

All, I have a `Task` that runs on a background thread and does some heavy lifting. The way I have it set up is that whilst this is being done, the UI thread updates the GUI with progress information, some of which use animated .gif files. Take a look at the following example code to illustrate the problem

```
TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task<bool> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    // Heavy work.
    if (heavyWorkCompleted)
        MethodToUpdateGui(uiScheduler); // Update DataGridView ImageCell on UI thread
    // More work.
}
```

I have a "In Progress" image that is shown in the appropriate DGV image cell during execution of "Heavy Work", if "Heavy Work" is successful this image changes to a tick (in DGV1), then `MethodToUpdateGui(uiScheduler)` uses this (just changed) image in DGV1 to update DGV2. However, when the `MethodToUpdateGui(uiScheduler)` runs it sometimes updates the DataGridView (DGV2) too fast. What I mean by this, is that the image is not the tick I want (and it should be due to successfull compleation) it is the "In Progress" image. It seems that the DGV is not updating fast enough for what I am doing.

Is there a better way to do this? Do I dare to spin the background thread after the GUI update to allow DGV1 to "catch-up" [this is nasty!]?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this? Do I dare to spin the background thread after the GUI update to allow DGV1 to "catch-up" [this is nasty!]?

The issue here is that that TPL uses [SynchronizationContext.Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) to send the message to the UI thread.  When the method runs, the Task will run asynchronously, which will, in turn, not update the GUI immediately.

If you want to make sure that the GUI is updated, the simplest option would be to have your `MethodToUpdateGui` block by waiting on the Task scheduled via `uiScheduler`.

This would look something like:

```
void MethodToUpdateGui(TaskScheduler uiScheduler)
{
    var updateTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
        // update gui
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);

    // Block until Task completes...
    updateTask.Wait();
}
```

This is better than trying to spin, as it will block and get notified by the TPL automatically.

This is effectively doing `Control.Invoke` instead of `Control.BeginInvoke`, in Windows Forms terminology.

Comment: I actually do this. In all GUI updates using `uiScheduler` I always use `uiTask.Wait()` (wrapped in a `try/catch` to catch any `AggregateException`s of course), but this "racing" is still happening!? I am confused...

Comment: @Killercam Are you doing a "completion" message the same way?

Comment: The compleation message is handled with a continuation. I don't wait on the continuation, and the continuation delegate is invoked well after this problem arises.

Comment: @Killercam That sounds like something is preventing the UI from updating, since the continuation won't run until the UI thread is free...

Comment: That's an idea. I will check this tomorrow. Thanks very much for your help and time.